# Function to rename fints series?

Tags: matlab

I'm using the Financial Toolbox to manage some time series data but I've not found a function to rename a data series inside the fints object. Does one exist?

In the following code I lag a series and then want to merge it back with the original, but only one version is kept because the series names are the same. In the second part I tear the lagObj apart, change the name and build a new lagObj2 which results in a merged fints object with two columns as expected.

Is there a function in the toolbox that does that, or is there someway to access the properties of an existing fints object so I could change the name in lagObj and not have to do this extra work?

```
data = (1:6)';
dates = (today:today+5)';
% Create fints and lagged versions
fintsObj = fints(dates, data);
lagObj = lagts(fintsObj);
% Both are called 'series1'
fieldnames(fintsObj, 1)
fieldnames(lagObj, 1)

% merged object has single series due to identical names
merge(fintsObj, lagObj, 'SortColumns', 0)

%% ----------------------------------------
% Tear apart lagObj and rename series
lagDates = lagObj.dates;
lagData  = fts2mat(lagObj);
lagNames = fieldnames(lagObj);

lagNames{4,1} = 'lagSeries1';

% Rebuild lagObj with new name
lagObj2 = fints(lagDates, lagData, lagNames{4,1});

%% -----------------------------------------
% Now merge has two series
merge(fintsObj, lagObj2, 'SortColumns', 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that you want is [`chfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/chfield.html) which allows you to change the name of your data series. Because you didn't specify the third input to `fints`, it defaulted to `series1`, `series2`, etc. Using `chfield` you can change the data series name of an `fints` object.

```
f = chfield(f, 'series1', 'MySeries');
```

For your specific example, this would look something like:

```
data = (1:6)';
dates = (today:today+5)';

% Create the initial time series object
fintsObj = fints(dates, data, 'Original');

% Change the field on the new time series object
lagObj = chfield(lagts(fintsObj), 'Original', 'Lag');

% Then merge
merge(fintsObj, lagObj, 'SortColumns', 0)

%   desc:   || LAGTS on
%   freq:  Unknown (0)
%
%   'dates:  (6)'    'Original:  (6)'    'Lag:  (6)'
%   '21-May-2016'    [             1]    [        0]
%   '22-May-2016'    [             2]    [        1]
%   '23-May-2016'    [             3]    [        2]
%   '24-May-2016'    [             4]    [        3]
%   '25-May-2016'    [             5]    [        4]
%   '26-May-2016'    [             6]    [        5]
```

Comment: Thanks Suever. Right there in the doc file but for some reason I just couldn't see it. I appreciate the response.